# ES6 Import some functions as a object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

actions.js

```
export const setX = () => {...}
export const setY = () => {...}
export const setT = () => {...}
```

somecomponent.js

```
import {setX, setY, setT} from 'actions'

export class somecomponent extends React.Component
{
   constructor(props,context)
   {
      super(props)
      this.state={
          X,
          Y,
          T
      }
   }


componentWillMount()
{
   let reduxstate = this.store.getState()
    Object.keys(this.state).forEach(n => {
      let fn = n + '-Changed';
      this[fn] = evt => {
        let update = {};
        update[n] = evt.target.value;
        this.setState(update);
        RETRIEVEDFUNCTION = ****//How to retrieve the imported actions setX,setY and setT by name****
        this.store.dispatch(RETRIEVEDFUNCTION(evt.target.value))
      }
      this.state[n] = reduxstate[n]
    });
}
```

Will all the imported functions be in the global 'window'. I was not able to find the imported function to access them by name

```
allimportedfunction['set'+n ](evt.target.value)
window['set'+n](evt.target.value)
```

or

is there way to add only the imported function into a object

```
import {setX, setY, setT} as actionCreators from 'actions'
actionCreators['set'+n ](evt.target.value)
```

import * as actionCreators from 'actions' -> This works, but I dont want to import all the functions

Comment: There is no global `window` in node.js.  Imports don't go into the node.js `global` object at all.  They go into the named local variables you defined and are not automatically in a parent object you can access them via.  To access them by name, you need to assign them into an object so you can then use that object to reference them.  Think of them like local variables in a function.  Same issue.  Put then in an object if you want to reference them by name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that.

But you can put them in an object:

```
import {setX, setY, setT} from 'actions'
const actionCreators = {setX, setY, setT};
```

Answer (score 5):

MDN has a good [overview of all forms of `import` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> import defaultMember from "module-name";
> import * as name from "module-name";
> import { member } from "module-name";
> import { member as alias } from "module-name";
> import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";
> import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
> import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
> import defaultMember, * as name from "module-name";
> import "module-name";
> ```

So, no, it's not possible with `import` alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you can turn on treeshaking which webpack provides, do as below

action.js

```
export const setX = () => {...}
export const setY = () => {...}
export const setT = () => {...}
export default { setX, setY, setT }
```

somecomponent.js

```
import actionCreators from 'actions'
console.log(actionCreators); // { setX, setY, setT }
```